# Log file created; But no logs are getting stored

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, logging, log4j

- IDE: STS(Eclipse)

Query #1:

I have created a SpringsMVC Project using Template available in STS tool(New->Springs Project-> Springs MVC Project). I am trying to use log4j. My problem is a new log file gets created in the specified location. But it remains empty and logs are not getting stored.

- File: web.xml

  ```
  <context-param>
      <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.properties</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
     <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  ```
- File: log4j.properties

  ```
  log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

  log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
  log4j.appender.FILE.File=D:/log.out

  log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
  log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
  ```

Query #2:
Also in the provided template there is already log4j.xml file in src/main/resources folder (a standard with resp to Maven web app). But modifying that file alone has no change in log file storage.

Answer (score 0):

By Default when STS create template and log4j then root logger defined for console appender.

You need to change for appending the log in file.

Define file appender first in log4j.xml.

```
 <appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="E:\\util.log" />
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
          <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%t %-5p %c{2} - %m%n"/>
        </layout>           
     </appender>
```

Then make change in root level.

```
<!-- Root Logger -->
<root>
<priority value="debug" />
<appender-ref ref="file" />
</root>
```

It will work.